# What would the new occupiers eat if they didn't harvest for 4 years

Tags: exodus, leviticus, canaan

Leviticus 19:23-25 stated that the Israelites when they newly occupy their land should dedicate the proceeds of planting for 3 years. They can only start eating it in the fifth year. To my knowledge, Manna stopped immediately they ate fruit of the land. My question is, what would they be eaten for the 4 years they weren't harvesting?

Comment: In most Bibles, Lev 19:23-25 has the Lord addressing eating/not eating fruit only.   https://biblehub.com/leviticus/19-25.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leviticus 19:23
New International Version

> "'When you enter the land and **plant** any kind of fruit tree, regard its fruit as forbidden. For three years you are to consider it forbidden; it must not be eaten.es

It refers to the newly planted fruit trees by the Israelites. The existing ones by the Canaanites were okay to eat.

Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers

> Shall have planted all manner of trees for food.--From this declaration the administrators of the law during the second Temple inferred that the trees planted by the inhabitants of Canaan before the Israelites took possession of it, were **exempt** from this law, and that it only applies to fruit-trees intended for food, such as citron-trees, olive-trees, fig-trees, vines, &c. Trees which bore fruit unfit for human food, which grew up by themselves, or which were planted for hedges or timber, did not come under this law.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in Deuteronomy 6:10-12:

> When the LORD your God brings you into the land that he swore to your
> fathers, to Abraham, to Isaac, and to Jacob, to give you — with great
> and good cities that you did not build, and houses full of all good
> things that you did not fill, and cisterns that you did not dig, and
> vineyards and olive trees that you did not plant — and when you eat
> and are full, then take care lest you forget the LORD, who brought you
> out of the land of Egypt, out of the house of slavery.

The people will find lots and lots to eat when they get there, along with vineyards and olive trees to grow more food. It's only their own newly planted trees that they can't eat from.